# Android build.xml renderscript doesn't support includepath

Tags: android, ant, hudson

I'm running my android project using ant in order to continuously run it using Hudson.  I have created my build.xml on my mac and instead of importing the generated android build.xml, I copy/pasted it in, since I have to customize some things.

It works fine on my local machine, however, when I run this on hudson, located on a server.  I run into an error with the Renderscript attribute.

```
renderscript doesn't support the "includePath" attribute
```

So, I decided to take OUT that line in the xml transforming this code:

```
 <renderscript executable="${renderscript}"
                includePath="${android.renderscript.include.path}"
                genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
                resFolder="${out.res.absolute.dir}/raw"
                targetApi="${project.minSdkVersion}"
                optLevel="${renderscript.opt.level}"
                buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}">
            <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
        </renderscript>
```

to this:

```
 <renderscript executable="${renderscript}"
                genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
                resFolder="${out.res.absolute.dir}/raw"
                targetApi="${project.minSdkVersion}"
                optLevel="${renderscript.opt.level}"
                buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}">
            <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
        </renderscript>
```

And then comically get this error:

```
RenderScriptTask's 'includePath' is required.
```

I'm running the same ant on both machines, downloaded the linux-specific SDK on the server, updated based on tools, platform-tools, and android-7 (the OS I'm supporting).  I've run out of ideas of what the problem could be, any help or pointers would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up happening because I had some files to be ignored via the classpath.  It was a simple, but overlooked mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This error happened because you updated the android sdk tools to revision to 20.0.1.

renderscript requires the property includePathRefId and it's path was changed. So your code should be:

```
<renderscript executable="${renderscript}"
            includePathRefId="android.renderscript.include.path"
            genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
            resFolder="${out.res.absolute.dir}/raw"
            targetApi="${project.minSdkVersion}"
            optLevel="${renderscript.opt.level}"
            buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
            previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}">
        <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
    </renderscript>
```

where the includePathRefId it should be defined like this:

```
<path id="android.renderscript.include.path">
    <pathelement location="${android.platform.tools.dir}/renderscript/include" />
    <pathelement location="${android.platform.tools.dir}/renderscript/clang-include" />
</path>
```